# A series for Fibonacci numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

How can I prove The Fibonacci sequence is encoded in the number $1/89$  i.e. $( 1/89 = 0.01 + 0.001 + 0.0002 + 0.00003 + 0.000005 + 0.0000008 + 0.00000013 + 0.000000021 + 0.0000000034 \ldots)$

Comment: Just evaluate the OGF in $z=\frac{1}{10}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: That question doesn't look like a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @Barak: It isn't one. It can be used to answer this one, but only by someone with suitable background. Someone without that background might well need a bit more explanation.

Comment: It looks to me that the point is just to compute $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{F_n}{10^n}.$$ The other question solves a more general problem, but the technique is just the same.

Answer (score 8):

If there were such $x$ ($ = 0.011235\ldots$), then this satisfies the property of Fibonacci sequence:
$$\begin{array}{lllllllll}
&0.&1&1&2&3&5&\ldots&//\ 10x\\
+&0.&0&1&1&2&3&\ldots&//\ x\\
\hline
&0.&1&2&3&5&9&\ldots\\
+&1\\
\hline
&1.&1&2&3&5&9&\ldots&//\ 100x
\end{array}
$$

So by solving for such $x$,
$$\begin{align*}
10x + x &= 100x - 1\\
89x &= 1\\
x &= \frac{1}{89}\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

I like peterwhy’s answer — think of this as an extended comment on it — but it does slide over a potentially tricky point: $x$ isn’t

$$\begin{array}{lll}
&0.&0&1&1&2&3&5&\color{brown}8&\color{brown}13&\ldots\;,
\end{array}$$

as the picture might suggest, but rather

$$\begin{array}{lll}
&0.&0&1&1&2&3&5&\color{brown}9&5&\ldots\;,
\end{array}$$

because of carries. We actually have

$$x=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{F_{n-1}}{10^n}\;.$$

Now we can carry out peterwhy’s calculation as follows:

$$\begin{align*}
0.01+0.1x+0.01x&=0.01+\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{F_{n-1}}{10^{n+1}}+\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{F_{n-1}}{10^{n+2}}\\\\
&=0.01+\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac{F_{n-2}}{10^n}+\sum_{n\ge 3}\frac{F_{n-3}}{10^n}\\\\
&=0.01+\frac{F_0}{10^2}+\sum_{n\ge 3}\frac{F_{n-2}+F_{n-3}}{10^n}\\\\
&=0.01+\sum_{n\ge 3}\frac{F_{n-1}}{10^n}\\\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{F_{n-1}}{10^n}\\\\
&=x\;,
\end{align*}$$

so $0.01=0.89x$, and $x=\dfrac1{89}$.